# Check with jQuery if an input is empty

Tags: jquery, forms, input

How can I check in jQuery if an input is empty ?

I tried:

```
$('#location').keydown(function(event) {
  if($("#location").val().length == 0 ) { $("#finalSearch").attr('disabled', 'true'); }
  if($("#location").val().length != 0 ) { $("#finalSearch").removeAttr('disabled'); }
});
```

But, I want the alert pop even if there's nothing in my field.

What I want to do:

- There's nothing: error message.
- There's one letter: no error message.
- I remove this letter: error message.
- If the field is populate but another function: no error message.

Thanks for help.

Comment: you can't detect field being filled by a function unless the other function triggers an event on the field and your handler code for the event then manages what you want

Comment: If 'keydown' event doesn't works for you, you must try 'keyup/keypress ' events with jquery events such as 'bind/delegate/on'. It should work on any one of these as i faced your issue several times before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `keyup` event rather than `keydown` - on key *down* the field hasn't updated yet so testing the `value` at that point doesn't give you the right result.

It wouldn't hurt to do the same test on `blur` too, to allow for if the user changed the field via the Edit menu or drag'n'drop or whatever.

Also, unless using a really old version of jQuery use the `.prop()` method rather than `.attr()` to set the disabled state:

```
$('#location').on('keyup blur', function(event) {
   $("#finalSearch").prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you're pretty much already there, not sure where the issue is for you; but this works.

```
$('#location').on('keyup', function() {
    console.log($(this).val().length);
    if($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $('#finalSearch').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $('#finalSearch').prop('disabled',false);
    }
});​
```

**[The jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aB7q3/)**

Comment: Solution was keyup. Thanks.